# Peskin QFT eq.(20.80) derivation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, standard-model, weak-interaction

In the derivation of electroweak current (P&S eq.(20.80)), we start with
$$\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\bar{E}_L(i \not D) E_L+\bar{e}_R(i \not D) e_R+\bar{Q}_L(i \not D) Q_L+\bar{u}_R(i \not D) u_R+\bar{d}_R(i \not D) d_R .
\end{equation} \tag{20.77} $$
using
$$\begin{equation}
D_\mu=\partial_\mu-i \frac{g}{\sqrt{2}}\left(W_\mu^{+} T^{+}+W_\mu^{-} T^{-}\right)-i \frac{g}{\cos \theta_w} Z_\mu\left(T^3-\sin ^2 \theta_w Q\right)-i e A_\mu Q,
\end{equation} \tag{20.71} $$
for example, lets's focus on $\bar{E}_L(i \not D) E_L$
with
$$\begin{equation}
E_L=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\nu_e \\
e^{-}
\end{array}\right)_L
\end{equation} \tag{20.75}$$
I thought
$$E_L= \nu_L + \gamma^0 e_L \quad \bar{E}_L= \bar{\nu}_L + \bar{e}_L  \gamma^0 $$
where
$$\begin{equation}
\nu_L=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\nu_{eL} \\
0
\end{array}\right) \quad e_L=\left(\begin{array}{c}
e^-_L \\
0
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation} $$
In the spinor representation:
$$T^- E_L = \gamma^0 \nu_L $$
So I came with below expression:
$$\bar{E} \gamma^{\mu} W_{\mu}^-T^-E_L =W_{\mu}^-(\bar{\nu}_L + \bar{e}_L  \gamma^0)\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^0 \nu_L= W_{\mu}^-\bar{e}_L  \gamma^0\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^0 \nu_L$$
but according to (20.80), the correct term should be
$$ W_{\mu}^-\bar{e}_L  \gamma^{\mu}  \nu_L $$
This two terms is clearly different for $\mu=i$, so where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let's me finish my post myself. I made a stupid mistake.

$E_L$ is a two-dim vector, in the $SU(2)\times U(1)$ generator space (here in basic rep.).  While $\nu_L$ and $e_L$ is four-dim in spinor space, where gamma matrices works. So I shouldn't mixed this two spaces.

For example:
$$ \bar{E}_L \gamma^{\mu} E_L= \left(\begin{array}{cc} \bar{\nu}_L & \bar{e}_L \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc} \gamma^{\mu} & 0 \\ 0 &\gamma^{\mu}\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c} \nu_L \\ e_L \end{array}\right)=\bar{\nu}_L \gamma^{\mu}\nu_L+\bar{e}_L \gamma^{\mu}e_L$$